# Family of analytic function uniformly continuous on compact set.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, compactness

> **Problem:** Fix $D \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ open, $K \subseteq D$ compact, $C>0$. Then for any $\varepsilon >0$ exists $\delta(D,C,K) > 0$ such that:
>
> *If $f: D \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is an analytic function, $|f(z)| \le C$, for all $z \in D$, then for all  $a,z \in K$, $ |f(z) -f(a)|< \varepsilon$ if $|z-a|<\delta$.*

My proof is below; is it right? I am happy to see any correct answers.

> **Proof:** For a closed disk $K = \bar{B}_R(a)$,  we have for all $z,w \in K$,
> $$ |f(z) - f(w)|  = \frac{1}{2 \pi }\oint_{|\zeta-a|=R} \Big| \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z} - \frac{\zeta}{\zeta-w} \Big| \, d\zeta.  \le \frac{2C}{R} |z-w| $$
> Thus, choose $2\delta_a < \min \{ R, \frac{R}{2C} \varepsilon \}$.  For arbitrary compact $K$: For each point $a \in K$ exists $2\delta_a$ derived above such that for all  $w,z \in B(a,2 \delta_a)$, $|f(z) -f(w)|< \varepsilon$.  Take a finite covering, of $K \subseteq \bigcup _i B(a_i, \delta_{a_i})$, and choose $\delta := \min_i \delta_{a_i}$. Then if $|z-w|< \delta$, $z,w \in B(a_j, 2 \delta_{a_j})$ for some $a_j$, with $|z-w|<2 \delta_{a_j}$ and $|f(z)-f(w)|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: I have not checked your work. But it suffices to show first that $f$ is continuous, because if $K$ is a compact metric space and $X$ is a metric space then any continuous $f:K\to X$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: I am showing the case for a family of analytic functions which satisfy the conditions (?) Why is that enough?

Comment: Sorry. I was thrown off by the capital letter on "If" in the problem. Make it look like a stand-alone sentence.